# Using Chrome on an Amazon Fire tablet, how can I revert Gmail to the version that was the default until yesterday?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome, amazon

Using Chrome on an Amazon Fire tablet, today I find Gmail  changed to a simplified version where the initial screen is a full-width inbox message list and little more. How can I revert it to the previous version?

Neither of the other options

[image]

do that. Both revert to even more primitive HTML versions.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the Opt-out instructions from [Learn about the new integrated Gmail layout](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/11555490?hl=en):

> #### Opt out of the new view
>
> 1. At the top right, click **Settings**
> 2. Under “Quick settings,” click **Go back to the original Gmail view**.
> 3. In the new window, click **Reload**.

Comment: "At the top right, click Settings" None is present.

Comment: Settings is the name of the gear icon (see the linked help article)

Comment: "Settings is the name of the gear icon" Not on the version in question. "(see the linked help article)" That's not the version in question. It doesn't remotely resemble my description. Note that the screenshot shows the version in question is "Mobile".